# How to have cout send to console and syslog simultaneously

Tags: c++, cout, syslog

Can anyone give a simple example of creating a customized cout, I would like to have MyCout class to print on console and send string to syslog at the same time.

```
MyCout myCout

myCout << "Test" << endl;
```

I need console output "Test" and "Test" sent to syslog.

Comment: It's not simple. Often we chose to instead build the output in a `stringstream` and then output the final result to both `cout` and the `syslog`.

Comment: FYI: you normally can't *guarantee* output sent to stdout is sent to the *console*. Users are free to redirect output wherever they please. If you want to *insist* on the console, then you have to write directly to the tty (assuming the process actually has one). Probably something like using the curses library.